# SQL Server Rename DB and Attached Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is there a simple way to rename a database, its `'mdf'` and `'log'` files with a single SQL script?

I got renaming working with the following script:

```
use [master]
ALTER DATABASE [sampleDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE    
ALTER DATABASE [sampleDB] MODIFY NAME = [newSampleDB]
ALTER DATABASE [newSampleDB] SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

This however will not take care of the `'mdf'` and `'log'` files which are named by the old name, and if I would create a new database called `sampleDB`, the files would conflict.

Is there any good solution to rename the files together with the database?

Comment: you could follow this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4419/renaming-physical-database-file-names-for-a-sql-server-database/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) to rename files on OS level. You must [enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option) it before using.

```
alter database oldDBName set offline
go

declare @cmd1 varchar(4000)
declare @cmd2 varchar(4000)

select @cmd1 = 'rename D:\path_to_file\oldDBName.mdf newDBName.mdf'
select @cmd2 = 'rename D:\path_to_file\oldDBName_log.ldf newDBName_log.ldf'
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd1
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd2
go

alter database oldDBName modify file (name = oldDBName, filename = 'D:\path_to_file\newDBName.mdf')
alter database oldDBName modify file (name = oldDBName_log, filename = 'D:\path_to_file\newDBName_log.ldf')
go

alter database oldDBName set online
```